# How to cast two flow types with a maybe attribute

Tags: ecmascript-6, flowtype

I want to cast the RedisGetHashJob to RedisKey type but I've an error...

My types:

```
export type RedisKey = {
  source: string,
  destination: string,
  type: string,
  id: string,
  groupId: string,
  pid?: string,
};

export type RedisGetHashJob = {
  source: string,
  destination: string,
  type: string,
  id: string,
  groupId: string,
  pid: string,
};
```

I've two functions:

1 - **function createKey(obj: RedisKey): string**

2 - **function getHashJob(obj: RedisGetHashJob): Promise**

In my second function, the pid attribute has to be set. But when I try to call it like:

```
function getHashJob(obj: RedisGetHashJob): Promise<string> {
  const key = createKey(obj);
  ....
}
```

I have the bellow error:

```
Error: src/common/lib/redis.js:60
 60:   const key = createKey(obj);
                             ^^^ object type. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
 15: export function createKey(obj: RedisKey): string {
                                    ^^^^^^^^ object type
  Property `pid` is incompatible:
      8:   pid?: string,
                 ^^^^^^ undefined. This type is incompatible with. See: src/types/redis.js:8
     26:   pid: string,
                ^^^^^^ string. See: src/types/redis.js:26
```

Do you know a pretty way to make this job ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you can delete `pid` property in `RedisKey` object and it will be still `RedisKey` object but not `RedisGetHashJob` anymore.
What if your `createKey` looks like

```
function createKey(obj: RedisKey): string {
  delete obj.pid
  return 'a';
}
```

To solve this you can copy obj before pass it to `createKey`:

```
function getHashJob(obj: RedisGetHashJob): Promise<string> {
  const objCopy = {...obj}
  const key = createKey(objCopy);
  ...
}
```

[Try it out](https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKwAmBLAzgaWETgF44BvAKDjlwgFcoBjYALlpimwDsBzAGmpxMwXDB4BDcRG7sxXPoJpIUczjwFDsmNQs01eUBmACSOjnqVww2gPy6NggL4BuSpVCRYCZKgw5cAHFgGAAJCVwACwApCAAjUgohOkYWB0UhETFJaVkLRyEVNnyMmm10-ThDYzMKqxtzeQLXdwAzem4mXLgmKGApYEJEAAp4gCt2fzwhgEoKpJoRABsQ1HGAOgahPphGbjgAcgkDtyc2jq7sGSqQ8KjYuNG4ifQsPGCwiJj4ubgABSMAFs8MAADxNPgAPgWPRkYjg4wAwhAwMQyOR1pjxmcaEw4fAANZERK9fowQZEJ5jZGomZuGg7Pb-IEg9Z9OhLABuwGGBziBxmlCcQA)